# PayerID missing intermitently in Paypal Express checkout on GetExpressCheckoutDetails

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I`m working for a company and we have a working PayPal express-checkout that works more or less flawlsessly, but from time to time we have requests that fail with "Express Checkout PayerID is missing". I have checked my logs and it is true that the PayerID is not being sent in those requests. I checked further and found out that this is because the "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" request doesen't return any PayerID in the first place, but, strangely it returns ACK="Success" (which leads my system to treat it as a successfull payment attempt). I had a look at the PayPal-API (NVP), but couldn't find any explanation for this scenario. Does anybody have an idea what could be happening here?. Is there something else that I am missing?.

The data I send with the request looks like that:

```
[METHOD] => GetExpressCheckoutDetails
[VERSION] => 53.0
[PWD] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[USER] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[SIGNATURE] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[TOKEN] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The data I recieve in the response looks like that:

```
[TOKEN] => THE TOKEN I SENT
[TIMESTAMP] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
[CORRELATIONID] => XXXXXXX
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 53.0
[BUILD] => 7319395
[CURRENCYCODE] => XXX
[AMT] => The value that was charged
[SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
[HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
[TAXAMT] => 0.00
[INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
[SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
```

Best regards, and thanks in advance

J. Illi

Comment: Are you doing anything different with the user_action on the redirect to PayPal?  I know if you use user_action=commit it will assume you're going to skip GECD and the PayerID will then be returned as URL parameter back to your ReturnURL so you would just use $_GET['PayerID'] in order to grab it.  I haven't specifically tested if it leaves it out of GECD, though.  I really don't think it would, but that's just something you might want to look into.

Comment: Can you share a recent (< 90 days old) EC token with me so I can review this?